# even I added database name to my mongo db url I got this error

Tags: java, mongodb, jdbc, automation, dependencies

even I added database name to my mongo db url I got this error
CONNECTION HAS FAILED There are issues with your connection settings : Mandatory property 'database' is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message you received, it seems like the connection URL you used is missing a required parameter: the database name.

Make sure that The connection URL for MongoDB should have the following format:

mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...]/database_name[?options]

Make sure that you have included the database name at the end of the URL, after the last forward slash (/).

If you have already included the database name in the URL and you are still receiving this error message, there could be other issues with your connection settings. Double-check that the username and password you provided are correct, and ensure that the host and port values are accurate for your MongoDB instance.

Additionally, you may want to check that your MongoDB server is up and running and accessible from your network.

Comment: jdbc:mongodb://host:27017/databasename this is working right console of intelij but when I setup automation I got this error